# How to push to vue-router without adding to history?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I have the following sequence happening:

- Main screen
- Loading screen
- Results screen

On homepage, when someone clicks a button, I send them to the loading screen, thru:

`this.$router.push({path: "/loading"});`

And once their task finishes, they are sent to the results screen via

`this.$router.push({path: "/results/xxxx"});`

The problem is, usually they want to go from results back to the main screen, but when they click back, they're sent to loading again which sends them back to results, so they're stuck in an infinite loop & unable to go back to main screen.

Any ideas how to fix this? I'd ideally like if there was an option like:

`this.$router.push({path: "/loading", addToHistory: false});`

which would send them to the route without adding it to history.

Comment: `this.$router.replace({path: "/results/xxxx"})`

Comment: @RolandStarke Thanks - this makes the back button work & go back to the main menu, but I lose the forward button & can't go forward again - any ideas?

Comment: The process is: Main menu, Loading, Results. I'm calling `$router.replace` from Loading. This now lets me go back from Results -> Main but I'm then unable to go forward to results.

Comment: Another option would be to not have a loading route. Rather push directly to the results route which does the data fetch on create, and then renders a loading view until it's complete. Then there's no re-routing and history and user flow should remain intact without $router.replace.

Comment: @ClickUpvote did you find any solution to this issue...

Comment: @ClickUpvote did any of these answers help you? do you mind selecting the answer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**There is a perfect way to handle this situation**

You can use [in-component guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) to control the route in granule level

Make the following changes in your code

**In main screen component**

> Add this beofreRouteLeave guard in component options, before leaving to 'result screen' you are setting the route to go only
>   through loading screen

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
   if (to.path == "/result") {
      next('/loading')
    }
    next();
  },
```

**In loading screen component**

> If the route go backs from result to loading then , it should not land
>   here and directly jump to main screen

```
beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    if (from.path == "/result") {
      next('/main')
    }
     next();
  },
```

> In loading screen, The beforeRouteEnter guard does NOT have access to
>   this, because the guard is called before the navigation is confirmed,
>   thus the new entering component has not even been created yet. So taking the advantage of this, you ***won't get the infinite calls*** fired when routing from results screen

**In result screen component**

> if you use go back then it should not land in loading and directly
>   jump to main screen

```
beforeRouteLeave(to, from, next) {
    if (to.path == "/loading") {
      next('/')
    }
    next();
  },
```

I have just created small vue application to reproduce the same issue. It works in my local as per your question. Hope it **resolves your issue** as well.

Comment: This solution is brittle (introduces maintenance tech debt) and requires entries for every possible route that you might need this functionality for.

Comment: Totally agree, i dont like this solution at all

Answer (score 22):

This should have a real answer using `this.$router.replace`:

```
// On login page

// Use 'push' to go to the loading page.
// This will add the login page to the history stack.
this.$router.push({path: "/loading"});

// Wait for tasks to finish

// Use 'replace' to go to the results page.
// This will not add '/loading' to the history stack.
this.$router.replace({path: "/results/xxxx"});
```

For further reading the Vue Router is using [History.pushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState) and [History.replaceState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) behind the scenes.

Answer (score 4):

I guess `router.replace` is the way to go - but still some lines of thought (untested):

---

Basically on `$router` change it renders the loading-component until it emits `load:stop`, then it renders the `router-view`

---

```
import { Vue, Component, Watch, Prop } from "vue-property-decorator";

@Component<RouteLoader>({
    render(h){
        const rv = (this.$slots.default || [])
        .find(
            child => child.componentOptions
            //@ts-ignore 
            && child.componentOptions.Ctor.extendedOptions.name === "RouterView"
        )
        if(rv === undefined) 
            throw new Error("RouterView is missing - add <router-view> to default slot")

        const loader = (this.$slots.default || [])
        .find(
            child => child.componentOptions
            //@ts-ignore 
            && child.componentOptions.Ctor.extendedOptions.name === this.loader
        )
        if(loader === undefined) 
            throw new Error("LoaderView is missing - add <loader-view> to default slot")
        const _vm = this 
        const loaderNode = loader.componentOptions && h(
            loader.componentOptions.Ctor,
            {
                on: {
                    // "load:start": () => this.loading = true,
                    "load:stop": () => _vm.loading = false
                },
                props: loader.componentOptions.propsData,
                //@ts-ignore
                attrs: loader.data.attrs
            }
        )
        return this.loading && loaderNode || rv
    }
})
export default class RouteLoader extends Vue {
    loading: boolean = false
    @Prop({default: "LoaderView"}) readonly loader!: string
    @Watch("$route")
    loads(nRoute: string, oRoute: string){
        this.loading = true
    }
}

@Component<Loader>({
    name: "LoaderView",
    async mounted(){

        await console.log("async call")
        this.$emit("load:stop")
        // this.$destroy()
    }
})
export class Loader extends Vue {}
```

Comment: This is the sort of implementation I'm talking about, though I tend to implement my loading component directly into my page components rather than creating a route watching wrapper. The reason being: I like to use the skeleton approach where the content component loads into a semi loaded state to give the user visual feedback of what to expect and then overlay the loading component (if it needs to block all actions) or inline it if the user can use the UI while data loads. It's all about user perception of speed and unblocking their ability to do what they want as quickly as possible.

Comment: @ArrayKnight thinking abstract one can simply exchange the router-view component with its coresponding route component and gets some kind of loader wrapper - but i agree putting the loader into the route feels like bad design

Answer (score 2):

This is a tough call considering how little we know about what's occurring in your loading route.

But...

I've never had a need to build a loading route, only ever loading component(s) that gets rendered on multiple routes during init/data gathering stage.

One argument for not having a loading route would be that a user could potentially navigate directly to this URL (accidentally) and then it seems like it wouldn't have enough context to know where to send the user or what action to take. Though this could mean that it falls through to an error route at this point. Overall, not a great experience.

Another is that if you simplify your routes, navigation between routes becomes much simpler and behaves as expected/desired without the use of `$router.replace`.

I understand this doesn't solve the question in the way you're asking. But I'd suggest rethinking this loading route.

**App**

```
<shell>
    <router-view></router-view>
</shell>

const routes = [
  { path: '/', component: Main },
  { path: '/results', component: Results }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
})

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app')
```

**Shell**

```
<div>
    <header>
        <nav>...</nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <slot></slot>
    </main>
</div>
```

**Main Page**

```
<section>
    <form>...</form>
</section>

{
    methods: {
        onSubmit() {
            // ...

            this.$router.push('/results')
        }
    }
}
```

**Results Page**

```
<section>
    <error v-if="error" :error="error" />
    <results v-if="!error" :loading="loading" :results="results" />
    <loading v-if="loading" :percentage="loadingPercentage" />
</section>

{
    components: {
        error: Error,
        results: Results,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            loading: false,
            error: null,
            results: null,
        }
    },
    created () {
        this.fetchData()
    },
    watch: {
        '$route': 'fetchData'
    },
    methods: {
        fetchData () {
            this.error = this.results = null
            this.loading = true

            getResults((err, results) => {
                this.loading = false

                if (err) {
                    this.error = err.toString()
                } else {
                    this.results = results
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**Results Component**

Basically the exact same results component you already have, but if `loading` is true, or if `results` is null, however you prefer, you can create a fake dataset to iterate over and create skeleton versions, if you'd like to. Otherwise, you can just keep things the way you have it.

Comment: The loading screen I have takes up the entire screen, so I can't think of a way to display it without having its own route. See https://naminator.io for a live demo. Open to any other ideas for doing this.

Comment: I'll give it a proper look in the morning, but my initial thought is there's no reason you couldn't use position fixed to take over the screen.

Comment: Looking at your design, it seems like there's a couple options: you could render the loader in place of the results content and then switch once data has been fetched; or you can overlay the loader of a skeleton of your results and then update and populate the results and remove the loader. Considering that the loader doesn't cover the header (site shell) you shouldn't need position fixed.

Comment: @ClickUpvote let me know how you feel about this approach.

Comment: @ArrayKnight,the question is routes are already implemented and its working as expected, this loading approach may not fit here, I have been through this same situation. The loading route can also have a form post request like payment gateway or some form post actions. In this scenario  we cannot comprise on removing a route. But still in vue router level we can have before enter guards, Why I suggested this approach is, vue instance of loading component is not yet created at this hook and its the advantage to decide whether to enter this route or not based on previous route

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the [History API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API).

Once you are in the Results screen, you can utilize the [ReplaceState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) to replace the URL in history of the browser.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the `beforeEach` hook of the router.

What you need to do is you must save a variable globally or in localStorage in the `loading` component when the data is loaded (before redirecting to the `results` component):

```
export default {
  name: "results",
  ...
  importantTask() {
    // do the important work...
    localStorage.setItem('DATA_LOADED', JSON.stringify(true));
    this.$router.push({path: "/results/xxxx"});
  }
}
```

And then you should check for this variable in the beforeEach hook and skip to the correct component:

```
// router.js...
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const dataLoaded = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('DATA_LOADED'));
  if (to.name === "loading" && dataLoaded)
  {
    if (from.name === "results")
    {
      next({ name: "main"} );
    }
    if (from.name === "main")
    {
      next({ name: "results"} );
    }
  }
  next();
});
```

Also, do remember to reset the value to false in your `main` component when the query button is clicked (before routing to the `loading` component):

```
export default {
  name: "main",
  ...
  queryButtonClicked() {
    localStorage.setItem('DATA_LOADED', JSON.stringify(false));
    this.$router.push({path: "/loading"});
  }
}
```

Comment: This solution is brittle (introduces maintenance tech debt) and requires entries for every possible route that you might need this functionality for.

Answer (score 0):

Your loading screen should not be controlled by vue-router at all.
The best option is to use a modal/overlay for your loading screen, controlled by javascript. There are lots of examples around for vue. If you cant find anything then vue-bootstrap has some easy examples to implement.